# Can't access foreignkey data of applicationUser, 'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Message'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Trying to add/Edit related data properties of applicationUser so notes can be recorded for users

ApplicationUser.cs

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public virtual ICollection<UserNote> UserNotes { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

UserNote.cs

```
    public class UserNote
{
    [Key]
    public int UserNoteId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(string id, ApplicationUser applicationUser)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var userFromDb = _db.ApplicationUser
                .Include(n => n.UserNotes)
                .Include(r => r.UserRoles)
                .AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
            UserNote note = _db.UserNote.Single(x => x.UserNoteId == 1);

            userFromDb.LastName = applicationUser.LastName;
            userFromDb.FirstName = applicationUser.FirstName;

            //Error accessing related data properties


            userFromDb.UserNotes.Message = applicationUser.UserNotes.Message;
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(applicationUser);
    }
```

I received 'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Message' and no accessible extension method 'Message' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection'

Answer (score 0):

`UserNotes` is a collection hence you need to access a certain index before getting its `Message` property.

```
// Use .Count to check if the list contains any number.

if(applicationUser.UserNotes.Count != 0){

   // .FirstOrDefault() will return the first object in that list, if there is none, it would return null.

   userFromDb.UserNotes.FirstOrDefault().Message = applicationUser.UserNotes.FirstOrDefault().Message;

}else{
   // this is just to let you know if it's empty just in case if you don't debug

   return Content("Your collection is empty.");
}
```

You could also use [.IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) or [.Where()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) with your list if you're looking for a specific record.

It's not entirely clear to me with what you're trying, if you're adding a new note or you're editing an existing note. Let me know further in the comments if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: I am trying up ad notes when editing a user, I tryied this approach and it removes the error. I still getting null error. I'm using include(), I'm must be missing something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the related data properties of applicationUser as follows :

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(string id, ApplicationUser applicationUser)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var userFromDb = _context.ApplicationUser
                .Include(n => n.UserNotes)
                .AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
            //UserNote note = _context.UserNote.Single(x => x.UserNoteId == 1);

            userFromDb.LastName = applicationUser.LastName;
            userFromDb.FirstName = applicationUser.FirstName;

            foreach (var usernote in applicationUser.UserNotes.ToList())
            {
                if (userFromDb.UserNotes.Any(un => un.UserNoteId == usernote.UserNoteId))
                {
                    userFromDb.UserNotes.Find(un => un.UserNoteId == usernote.UserNoteId).Message = usernote.Message;
                }
            }

            _context.Update(userFromDb);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(applicationUser);
    }
```